# How to select (everything) one row in table 1 which has another row that is the same as table 2

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I am a beginner and I need to complete this SQL statement. So, I need to know how you would go about with searching for a name, then on the same table, select the id associated with the name. Then grab the row from another table with that same id. I want it so the user does not see the id and only needs to enter the name.

example:

```
table1       table2
 name       member_id
  id        other-info
 other
 info
```

would it be something like this,:

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.id, table1.other-info, 
       table2.member_id, table2.other-info
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id, table2,member_id
```

but with that, how do I enter my name?

**(tried it but it doesn't do anything, no output)**
This is my connection.php

```
<?php
$user="root";
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname="test";
$tablename="table1, table2";
$pass="";

$conn= new mysqli($servername,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    echo(" Connected to the database ");
}
```

**this is my display.php**

```
SELECT table1, table2
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id= t2.member_id
where t1.name = 'my own example'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for searching a specific name you need to put where condition end of join, using table alias is a good practice

```
SELECT t1.name, 
t1.id, 
t1.other-info,
 t2.member_id, t2.other-info
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id= t2.member_id
where t1.name = 'Tuhin' //put here your searching name
```

Comment: @userpyth i have not understand properly what you mean but it seems to me you want to  write inselect  like select t1.*,t2.* this , btw if my answer helps please accept the answer

Comment: i tried this code and there is no errors but nothing shows up also.

Comment: @userpyth have you changed  t1.name ='' your searching name??? or share some sample data with us so that we can guide more easily

Comment: i did change the name, and how do you want me to share the data becuase here is a limit, do u want me to open another question?

Comment: @userpyth i don't think you need to open another question just edit question and put two tables sample data and expected output

Comment: there I did it.

Comment: @userpyth this is php code not sql editor ,so 1st run the code in sql editor like workbench or phpmyadmin then put this sql in php code

Comment: hey, so I figured out that in my select, I could not just put table1 and table2 but I have to put individual ones like table1.ID... So I have much stuff that would go here but I want the whole table all in one select. Right now, it thinks that I am adding rows from my table and not the whole table.

Comment: i ended up using $sql= SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1_ID = table2_Member_ID AND Table_1_Name = (my value here)

Comment: $sql= select * FROM  table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON  table_1_ID = table2_Member_ID 
where Table_1_Name  =(my value here) is better approach always